# Using FaceID or TouchID to authenticate a signed in user when coming back from background

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, face-id

I have an app that I need to be very secure. As such, a user foregrounding the app needs to be verify themselves via TouchID, FaceID or their phone pin to continue.

I'm able to display and remove the `coverVC`, but in my `BackgroundViewController` (the one that acts as the `coverVC`), I want to prompt the user to bio authenticate when the app is in the foreground

I'm trying to pass a `handler` function into the `BackgroundViewController` to trigger at the right time but it isn't working and I'm not clear what I'm doing wrong. Would love any help here. Thanks!

In my `AppDelegate`:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    coverVC = BackgroundViewController()
    coverWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let existingTopWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last

    coverWindow?.windowLevel = existingTopWindow!.windowLevel + 1
    coverVC!.view.frame = coverWindow!.bounds
    coverWindow?.rootViewController = coverVC
    coverWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    if coverWindow != nil {
        self.coverVC?.handler = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    self.coverVC?.view.alpha = 0
                }) { _ in
                    self.coverWindow!.isHidden = true
                    self.coverWindow!.rootViewController = nil
                    self.coverWindow = nil
                    self.coverVC = nil
                }
            }
        }

        self.coverVC?.authenticateReturningUser()
    }
}
```

In my `BackgroundViewController.swift`:

```
class BackgroundViewController: UIViewController {
   var handler: (() -> Void) = {}

   (viewDidLoad and other stuff in here)

   func authenticateReturningUser() {
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Verify that this is your device to continue."

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason) { [weak self] success, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    if let _self = self {
                        _self.handler()
                    } else {
                        print("this is hitting")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private func showError(title: String, message: String, buttonText text: String = "Okay") {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: text, style: .default) { _ in
        self.handler()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "LogOut"), object: nil)
    })

    present(ac, animated: true)
}
```

**Edit:**

If I set `[weak self]` to `[unowned self]` and call `self.handler()`, I get:

> Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but the object was already deallocated

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: `self` is nil in `authenticateReturningUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `context` object is being deallocated.

Change your code to this, so the context object has a reference

```
var context: LAContext!
func authenticateReturningUser() {
    context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Verify that this is your device to continue."

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason) { [weak self] success, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    if let _self = self {
                        _self.handler()
                    } else {
                        print("this is hitting")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to take out the [weak self] and everything worked

Comment: Sure thing, there isn't really any need for a `[weak self]` in that case anyway, as you want and expect self to be retained while the iPhone does whatever it needs to do.

Comment: The only issue here it that the app keeps asking for my finger print after the successful authentication. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: I don't know that particular API, but maybe you need to dismiss it manually? Maybe check if you're calling `authenticateReturningUser` recursively in your `self.handler()`!

Comment: `authenticateReturningUser` is definitely outside of the `handler`.

Comment: Hmm. And there's no code in your `handler` that could lead to some code path that calls it?